# How can I refactor Api::SessionsController?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, ruby-on-rails, api, session

I have session controller for mobile devices. I would like to refactor it a little, for example because my session controller is sub class of `Devise::SessionsController` I had to duplicate error methods from `BaseController`.

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:create]
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :ensure_params_exist, only: [:create]

  respond_to :json

  def create
    if user_find params[:user][:member_id]
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      resource.reset_authentication_token!
      resource.save!
    else
      error :not_found
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out(resource_name)
  end

  private

  def user_find(id)
    User.find_by member_id: id
  end

  def ensure_params_exist
    unless params[:user]
      error :bad_request
    end
  end

  def error type, context=nil
    render json: { message: error_message(type, context) }, status: type
  end

  def error_message type, context
    scope = [:api, :error, self.controller_name.to_sym]
    scope.push context if context
    t(type, scope: scope)
  end

end

class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  respond_to :json

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    render_status :unauthorized
  end

  private

  def error type, context=nil
    render json: {message: error_message(type, context)}, status: type
  end

  def error_message type, context
    scope = [:api, :error, self.controller_name.to_sym]
    scope.push context if context
    t(type, scope: scope)
  end

  def render_status state
    render status: state, json: {}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the common error methods in a Module and include it in each Controller where you need them (in a similar way like you already include `Devise::Controllers::Helpers`, but this time with your own namespace and module name.)

As for the method signatures

```
def error type, context=nil
def error_message type, context
def render_status state
```

it's common to leave the parenthesis out when calling class methods in class context (because they oftentimes make up a nice DSL), but please don't do it when defining methods, that can lead to annoying ambiguities.